# Aligning background image to right

Tags: css, image, html

http://jsfiddle.net/Zx836/

In the second box, notice how the arrow is in the same place. How can I make it flow with the div?

Using `scroll right center` in the `background` property works but I want to keep some padding right.

I'm also trying to avoid using 2 divs or the  tag. Is this possible just via the .`box` div?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about adding the image using `:after` instead?

```
.box {
    background: #a6cf83;
    float:left;
    color:#333;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:8px;
}

.box:after {
    content: url(http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/humano2/24x24/actions/new-go-next.png);
}
```

Answer (score 39):

```css
.right-align-background {
    background-position: center right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Zx836/1/

Comment: Thanks, as specified that works yes, but I need a padding to the right like in the first box. With `center right` the arrow is pushed to the limit.

Comment: best cross browser solution!

Comment: Best answer *imo

Answer (score 16):

You could also use `background-origin: content-box;` if your you would like your background to line up with the padding you set on the element.

Something like this:

```
input.error {
 background: no-repeat;
 background-image: url('../images/field-error.png');
 background-position: right center;
 background-origin: content-box;
 padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Didn't even know this existed! Perfect solution

Answer (score 3):

[Calc() has 95% browser support in the US now](https://caniuse.com/#search=calc()) (September, 2017), and provides an elegant solution to this problem.

```
background-position: calc(100% - 24px) center;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need padding on the right, I think you might have to go with percentages :

```
background-position:95% 50%;
```

will do quite nicely if your elements are of similar width.